Vercel AI SDK image prompt, The image was specified using the image/jpeg media type, but does not appear to be a valid jpeg image
I'm trying to generate a object with a image using vercel's ai sdk. I'm having trouble with uploading a image. I'm trying to upload a base64string of my image.
If I remove the image, text generation works fine.
I get this error
The image was specified using the image/jpeg media type, but does not appear to be a valid jpeg image
server
export async function POST(req) {
  let text = await req.text()

  try {
    const { object } = await generateObject({
      model: anthropic('claude-3-haiku-20240307'),
      schema: z.object({
        recipe: z.object({
          name: z.string(),
          ingredients: z.array(
            z.object({
              name: z.string(),
              amount: z.string()
            })
          ),
          steps: z.array(z.string())
        })
      }),
      messages: [
        {
          role: 'user',
          content: [
            {
              type: 'text',
              text: 'list all the stamps in these passport pages?'
            },
            {
              type: 'image',
              image: cleanBase64(text)
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })

    console.log(object)


    return Response.json({ message: "success" });

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return Response.json({ message: "fail" });

  }
}


client
           reader.onload = async function (e) {
                setIsLoading(true)
                const string = e.target.result;
                
                await fetch('/api/activities', {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: string,
                })
          
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);


I have tried passing my base64string as a json and then parsing it on my route handler
I have tried cleaning my base64string
